# Não consigo fazer o "web scraping" adequadamente de um site de tirinhas em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Bom, estava eu fazendo um código que verificaria o dia de cada tirinha/gif da página e, se o dia for o mesmo que o dia atual(no código eu coloquei 14 somente porque o site não atualiza final de semana e eu precisava testar de alguma forma), eu baixaria a tirinha/gif. Porém, dois erros ocorrem: o código não faz download de todas as tirinhas/gifs(percebi um padrão de até 5 tirinhas baixadas,nada além disso), além disso, as vezes mesmo quando a data é menor que a data atual, o código faz o download do mesmo jeito.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime
import os

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Rafael\\Desktop\\Scraping\\leninja_imgs')

def get_img():
    r = requests.get("https://leninja.com.br/page/2/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    daysPost = soup.select(".day-post")
    imgLinks = [i.get("src") for i in soup.select(".le-inner-content img")]
    #actualday = datetime.datetime.now().day
    actualday = 14
    n = 0

    for day in daysPost:
        if int(day.getText()) == actualday:
            req = requests.get(imgLinks[n])
            img = open(os.path.basename(imgLinks[n]), "wb")

            for chunk in req.iter_content(100000):
                img.write(chunk)    

        else:
            print("Não foi possível baixar a imagem!")
            return False
        n += 1
    return True

get_img()
```

Answer (score 0):

As imagens são uma lista, assim dá para descarregar todas:

```
# coding=utf-8

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime
import os

os.chdir('./')

def get_img():
    r = requests.get("https://leninja.com.br/page/2/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    daysPost = soup.select(".day-post")
    imgLinks = [i.get("src") for i in soup.select(".le-inner-content img")]
    #actualday = datetime.datetime.now().day
    actualday = 20
    n = 0

    for img in imgLinks:
        try:
            req = requests.get(imgLinks[n])


        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print e
            print("Não foi possível baixar a imagem!")
            return False

        img = open(os.path.basename(imgLinks[n]), "wb")

        for chunk in req.iter_content(100000):
            img.write(chunk)
        n += 1
    return True

get_img()
```